# Is it possible to have a script run when a spreadsheet dropdown is selected?

Tags: google-apps-script

I ask if it is possible to make the `line()` below execute when one is selected from the drop-down list in the sheet.

The important thing is “Run a specific script when selected from the drop-down list”.

Please understand that the content of the question is not natural by using a translator.

```
function line() {
Scheduled to change the border thickness and color of a specific cell
};
```

I'm just starting out, so I can't find a way

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can you provide your current script? And can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal? For example, from `Is it possible to have a script run when a spreadsheet dropdown is selected?`, do you need an answer yes or no about whether your goal can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

```
I am not sure I understood your question completely, but in case that you need the possibility to activate the script by selecting a certain value in a dropdown, maybe this could help:
```

```
        function onEdit(e)
    {
      if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'ENTER_HERE_CELL_WHERE_YOUR_DROPDOWN_IS' && e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == 'ENTER_HERE_NAME_OF_THE_SHEET') {       
          eval(e.value)();
          e.range.clear();


      }
    }
    
    /////you can change this function name to be "function line(){"
    function dropdown_value1(){ 
        ///do something
    }
    
    function dropdown_value2(){
        ///do something else
    }
```

```
Above example is in case that you have dropdown menu, where two values are options to be selected: dropdown_value1 and dropdown_value2.
```